# Ubuntu 15.04: gdigi not working

Tags: 15.04

I just installed Ubuntu 15.04 yesterday and I have been trying to get gdigi working with my RP500. I have managed to successfully install gdigi 0.4.1, but when I try to launch it nothing happens. When I try to launch it from terminal I get this error

```
** (gdigi:17336): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-UoxDR0f4if: Connection refused
**
ERROR:gui.c:760:update_modifier_vbox: assertion failed: (group[x].label)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any help is warmly welcomed!

Comment: Not easy to debug: `** (gdigi:5189): WARNING **: Couldn't find DigiTech devices!` ;)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem compiling `gdigi` from the source:

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/desowin/gdigi.git
cd gdigi
sudo make
./gdigi
```

Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

First I removed the packages using synaptic. Then I was able to follow above advice successfully!!!

I fixed this problem compiling gdigi from the source:

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/desowin/gdigi.git
cd gdigi
sudo make
./gdigi
```

Hope it works for you!